# Running old mean stack project in latest versions of node and angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular, npm, mean-stack

I wanna run this project in my local machine 
https://github.com/Logician724/Mini-Ebay
But this project was developed 2 years ago 
Can i run this project on my local machine where angular 9 and node 12 are installed or should I downgrade both of them to match the project's version?
And should i even downgrade my npm version?

Answer (score 0):

The angular version doesn't matter as Node will download your dependencies based on package.json.

You could have issues with the Node version. I recommend you to install with you current version of Node and check if it runs or or if it doesn't.
If it doesn't then you need to update some of the dependencies. Which you should anyways if you are planning to revive and old project.

You can also look into Docker to run it in a container with a Node version from two years ago. This may be easier and quicker than upgrading the dependencies and the code. (And neater too.)

In general you would not want to downgrade you development environment. We should go forward rather than backward.

Comment: there are 2 folders in that project-backend(nodejs) and frontend(angular)
In the backend, when i run npm install there are no errors
But in the backend, i run the same command i get a lot of errors about sass and others
and it shows built failed with error code-1